# Magento 2: Admin Dashboard is not loading after login

Tags: magento2

I just observed my admin dashboard isn't loading properly after login. i have cleared cache and still isn't loading fine. Screenshots how its loading below. Will appreciate any tips in identifying the issue and resolution

[image]

Comment: see console errors.

Comment: your static deployment is not done. please check it and try to run 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade and check all pub/static files exist or not.

Comment: @RonakChauhan i have done my static deployment and still faced with the issue..

Comment: @SaifZakir i have this on my console      JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1

Comment: check your .htaccess file is placed under pub/static folder with permission.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Delete all folders under pub/static
Delete var/cache
Delete var/composer_home
Delete var/generation
Delete var/page_cache
Delete var/view_preprocessed
```

Then run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Answer (score 0):

Check .**htaccess** is available in your Magento root folder. If it's not there then just add the .htaccess file in the root folder.